# Visual Studio code depicts under Problems vue.config.js "}" expected but app runs

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to configure a proxy in vue.config.js in visual studio code.
For the following code I receive '}' expected listed under prolems in visual studio code.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    proxy: {
      "/rest/": {
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
};
```

Comment: Is the code working though? Or is this an error that the editor is giving you? Sometimes the IDE can be slow to update or updates after a keystroke or saving the file.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: thanks, the app runs but visual studio code (the development environment) depicts the Problem.